# How to hide and show divs on button click created dynamically in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I have dynamically created buttons and divs, I want to show div on click of associated button and hide the rest. I don't know the count as they are creating dynamically. How to do it in vue js?

```
<div style="margin-left: -88px;margin-top: 20px;">

<button v-for="namelock in tour_location"  style="background-color:#EFF5FA;border: 0;border-radius: 15px;font-size: 14px;margin-left: 60px;">{{namelock.name}}</button>



<div v-for="(location,index ) in tour_location">

<h1>My Dynamic data</h1></div>
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have add code in my question, I have tried v-if before but for that i have to initialize variables first that i dont want as this data is dynamic

Comment: Can you us what an example of array that you are using in `v-for`?
and the condition of when to show the button or not

Comment: I just what to click on button and the associated div should show like in tab menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `v-show`, change the show prop @click into an id of the object you want to show then on `v-show` you can check if the show prop is equal to the object id that you want to show

```
<div id="app">
  <button v-for="b in buttons" @click='show = b' class="btn m-4 btn-primary">{{b}}</button>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div v-show="show === d.id" v-for='d in divs' class="col-sm-3 m-2">
        {{d.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in vue script

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    buttons: [1,2,3],
    divs: [{id:1,name:'apple'},{id:2,name:'mango'},{id:3,name:'banana'}],
    show: null
  },
})
```

Heres the working code in the
[Code pen](https://codepen.io/presmelito-rapatan-villanueva/pen/eYmBKGN?editors=1010)

Comment: hey thanks for your answer, one more thing : how can we make first div active by default as right now I need to click first to show div when page loads first time.

Comment: Well, you can change the show prop to the id of the first object instead of null to show it by default. 
`show: 1`